# Setting up or manipulating Sitecore publish restrictions programatically

Tags: publishing

Could somebody please explain to me how to manipulate publishing restrictions from a code.
I would like to be able to mark some certain versions as Publishable/NonPublishable  in a similar way as it could be done in PublishingSettings window:
[image]

In API, I can see few methods, which looks like similar to this functionality available in UI, however their signatures are not very self-explaining.
For instance there is something like:

```
myItem.Versions.GetLatestVersion().Publishing.IsPublishable(DateTime date, bool checkAncestors)
myItem.Versions.GetLatestVersion().Publishing.HideVersion
```

or 
`myItem.Versions.GetLatestVersion().Publishing.NeverPublish`, which obviously is not what I need.

We are lucky to have Sitecore 7.5 and I couldn't find anything relevant on SDN (maybe checked wrong documents though)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

It is `HideVersion` field which you want to use, e.g.:

```
var itemVersions = item.Versions.GetVersions();

var notPublishableVersion = itemVersions[i];
notPublishableVersion.Editing.BeginEdit();
notPublishableVersion[FieldIDs.HideVersion] = "1";
notPublishableVersion.Editing.EndEdit();

var publishableVersion = itemVersions[j];
publishableVersion.Editing.BeginEdit();
publishableVersion[FieldIDs.HideVersion] = string.Empty;
publishableVersion.Editing.EndEdit();
```